# Unable to Install Canon Solution Disc

Tags: canon, eos-utility, os-x

I just got a mini DVD with some software which will probably help me downloading the photos from my Canon 600D using the interface cable but I have a mac and it does not have a DVD drive.

I tried to download solution-disk29.1a.dmg.zip from Canon website but it says you need to be Administrator to install this and not prompting any password.

Is this the correct software (EOS Utility) I am trying to install ? Any workaround of this problem ?

My account is already admin.

OSX Yosemite.

[image: Admin Account]

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Although this is software related to your camera, you'll probably have better results asking this on http://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any software to download the images from your camera. Just plug it in. Use iPhoto or Lightroom, etc, and they can download directly.

You can also launch Image Capture, which is built into your Mac. This app will likely show your camera being attached, and offers the ability for you to define which application launches when it is attached.

EOS Utility is a camera control application, and the disk also usually contains a few Canon apps for managing images.

In my personal experience, the installer is very un-Mac like, and seems to have difficulty installing at times. It would not surprise me if it were incompatible with Yosemite.

Comment: I totally agree with "cmason". with everything mentioned above and whats possible with Yosemite, you don't have to have the Canon Utilities. If however you do want it, the version downloaded is the correct version, but for some reason, your Mac is pointing out that if you are not the main user of the Mac, then you need to ask the person whom the laptop belongs to, for them to install for you. it maybe set up so that extra users do not get the option for  password! otherwise, an incompatibility issue.

Comment: Awesome ! iPhoto, Image Capture and Picasa works. That's all I needed, so that I don't do much mechanical movement with the card. Hope I am not missing out any Canon Utility function.

Comment: There's no need to fear removing the card. SD sockets typically have a 10,000 insertion cycle rating: you could remove and replace the card 2-3 times per day, every day, for 10 years before you'd expect to see a problem. You'll probably wear out the shutter long before you wear out the card connector.